# What effect does wearing heavy armor have?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

So the description for some armors talk about how heavy they are, which implies they have some impact on your agility (movement speed, stamina consumption, et cetera). Considering how expensive the armor is I don't want to just toss away my rupees without knowing how exactly it impacts my characters agility.

What effect does heavy armor, like Soldiers Armor, have on Link?

Comment: You make more noise for one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I bought the hyrule soldier armor in Hateno village (full metal heavy armor) and have been running around with it for at least 8-10 hours of game time. I have tried to carefully track its' side effects, since I also expected to move more slowly.

I just did some user tests to be sure, and this is what I can say for sure:

Running speed and stamina are not affected. Climbing speed and stamina are not affected. Dodging and jumping distance is not affected. These all work exactly the same. The speed is the same, and it consumes stamina at the same rate. I tried it with cloth armor and the hyrule soldier metal armor multiple times, there were no differences.

Even the noise meter was the same for sneaking. I had no issues with sneaking up on horses or enemies.

Metal armor doesn't even affect lightning strikes either.

Comment: The last sentence is false; metal armor does not affect lightning strikes.

Comment: @Gendolkari good call - I've known this for quite a while now but forgot about this answer haha. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I used heavy armor for a few boss fights, and my experience is that it just gives more defense (and if it's the Knight set you're talking about, no set bonus :(). I can't confirm or deny more noise like @Ramhound suggests, and I don't notice any additional stamina consumption. You definitely move around at the same pace as with normal armor, can glide normally, etc.